# Ruby: How to pass options to user_timeline method of twitter gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

I am using [sferik gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to get tweets.

I want to pass following extra parameters to method "user_timeline":

count, include_rts and exclude_replies

Is it possible to pass these in as parameters?

If yes, how can I pass these extra parameters to "user_timeline" method and get the appropriate response back according to these extra params?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter%2FREST%2FTimelines%3Auser_timeline). You should be able to pass the supported options like so:

```
user_timeline(your_user, {
 :include_rts => true,
 :exclude_replies => true,
 :count => 42 
})
```

**Update**
As @mudasobwa correctly pointed out in the comment, if you are using `ruby 1.9+`, you can use the simpler syntax below:

```
user_timeline(your_user, include_rts: true, exclude_replies: true, count: 42)
```

Comment: As by Ruby 1.9, curly brackets and hashrocket syntax is kinda obsolete: `user_timeline(your_user, include_rts: true, exclude_replies: true, count: 42)`.

Comment: absolutely!  just trying to be safe because OP never mentioned the version.

Comment: Thanks @Shaunak and @mudasobwa!!